# Pycharm delete redundant database consoles

Tags: pycharm

When I choose jump to consoles in Pycharm ,there are always some consoles that I created before by mistake.But now, I want to delete the redundant ones and use the default one only.Can you tell me what should I do to delete them? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[look this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ru9V.png)

select and right-click on it